# Why isn't this function removing the vowels?

Tags: javascript

I created a function that takes a string converts the string to an array and then compares each string character to each vowel in an array, removing the string character if it matches one. It doesnt seems to be working correctly on longer words. For example with "tom" the o would be removed but with "johnson" only the first o is removed and then the n is removed at the end as well. I'm not seeing the issue.

```js
function removeVolwels(string){

  let strAr= function(string){
     //converts to to lower case and turns string into an array
      let s= string.toLowerCase();
      let strAr= s.split("");
      return strAr;
  }(string);
   //stores vowels
  let vowels=["a","e","o","i","u","y"];

  //loops through each character
  for(let i=0; i < string.length -1; i++){
      console.log("i index " + i);
  //compares each  character in the string to a every vowel until it matches one
      for(let j=0; j < vowels.length; j++){
          console.log("j index " + j + " and " +vowels[j]);
         if(string[i] === vowels[j]){
              console.log(string[i].toString() + " === "+vowels[j]);
             console.log("removed " + string[i]);
            //removes vowel if letter matches one
             strAr.splice(i,1);
             console.log(strAr)
         } 
      }
  }
  
  return strAr.join("");
}

console.log('tom => ' + removeVolwels('tom'));
console.log('johnson => ' + removeVolwels('johnson'));
```

Comment: I think because you've already removed one character, it's then counting the length wrong and removing a character 1 later in the string than it should. I haven't proved that but that's my suspicion.

Comment: I think your second can just simply be: `let strAr = string.toLowerCase()s.split("");`

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop on a string that is continually changing size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you call `strAr.splice(i,1);`.

So, you have word "johnson", and after removing first "o" you've got "jhnson", but current length of string is 6 instead of 7 in the beginning!

When you get to next "o" - `i` have value of 5 (which is correct for "johnson" string but not "jhnson").

Also, there is another bug in loop - you have condition `i < string.length -1`. That means you will never reach last character. It should be `i < string.length`.

So, if you want to reuse your solution you can write something like this:

```js
function removeVolwels(string){

  let strAr= function(string){
     //converts to to lower case and turns string into an array
      let s= string.toLowerCase();
      let strAr= s.split("");
      return strAr;
  }(string);
   //stores vowels
  let vowels=["a","e","o","i","u","y"];
  let returnVal = [];
  //loops through each character
  for(let i=0; i < string.length; i++){
      console.log("i index " + i);
      // simple flag to match if letter should be added to return array
      let shouldBeAdded = true;
      //compares each  character in the string to a every vowel until it matches one
      for(let j=0; j < vowels.length; j++){
          console.log("j index " + j + " and " +vowels[j]);
          if(string[i] === vowels[j]){
              // when it is some of the vowels it should not be added, so we change the flag, and break 'vowel loop'
              shouldBeAdded = false;
              break;
          } 
      }
      // if flag is true then add letter to result array
      if(shouldBeAdded === true) {
          returnVal.push(string[i])
      }
  }
  
  return returnVal.join("");
}

console.log('tom => ' + removeVolwels('tom'));
console.log('johnson => ' + removeVolwels('johnson'));
```

Comment: To be fair, pointing out the problem does answer what the OP asked for in this case. The question specifically was "Why does this code not work, I don't see the issue". In both cases, the responses did point out the problem. It would be better to post a solution, but its incorrect to say the answers were not useful.

Comment: @user1361529 you'll find generally most people don't ask for a solution explicitly, they simply state somethings not working and they don't know what to do about it. But on a programming site it's not unreasonable to expect that an answer to a code problem might include some code to fix it. That's what occurs in 90% of cases.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be overcomplicating things a bit. Below is a much more streamlined way of doing what you're after (code commented).

```js
function removeVowels(string) {
  // convert string to lowercase and split into array 's'
  let s = string.toLowerCase().split("");

  // define our list of vowels
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "o", "i", "u", "y"];

  // loop over array 's' in reverse. if the letter we're iterating over is in the vowels array, remove it. We do this in reverse because we'd skip letters if we went from front to back due to the splice.
  for (let i = s.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (vowels.indexOf(s[i]) > -1) {
      s.splice(i, 1); // 'i' is the index to start at (which we get from our loop) and 1 is the number of characters to remove.
    }
  }
  return s.join("");
}

console.log('tom => ' + removeVowels('tom'));
console.log('johnson => ' + removeVowels('johnson'));
console.log('aoeieyyozoyyeieoa => ' + removeVowels('aoeieyyozoyyeieoa'));
```

Comment: FWIW, these days you can also use `Array.from(string)` to create an array from a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because after executing,

```
strAr.splice(i,1)
```

index in original string and index in strAr are not same for the same character.
So, you need to twist your logic for that.

Comment: And what should be done instead? Pointing out the _problem_ doesn't really constitute a _solution_

Comment: Yes, you are right @ADyson, Sorry my bad.  Here we can keep track how many elements are removed by using count and calculate the index to remove by subtracting it from string index that is 'i'

Comment: You should update your answer itself with any suggestions and code for solving it :-)

Comment: yes I also realized that. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach that utilizes [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),[`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods. The following code also uses [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to convert a string into a character array:

```js
//1st param is the string you want to remove letters from
//2nd param is an array containing the letters to remove
function removeLetters(str, toRemove) {
  //Create an array - each index contains a single character
  let letters = str.split('');

  //Use Array.prototype.filter method to remove any letter that occurs in "toRemove" array
  let filtered = letters.filter(letter => toRemove.indexOf(letter) === -1)

  //Turn the filtered array back into a string
  return filtered.join('');
}

//The letters we want to remove are all vowels, so:
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'];

//Some test cases
const word = "tommy";
const word2 = "johnson";
const word3 = "aeioux";
console.log(removeLetters(word, vowels));
console.log(removeLetters(word2, vowels));
console.log(removeLetters(word3, vowels));
```

Comment: If you downvote, could you please at least have the courtesy to leave a comment explaining why? Thanks.

Comment: you haven't explained your code...which is why you might be getting downvotes. What you've written is quite different to the original, but you haven't shown the OP how/why it works. It's not just correcting a typo or adding a line or two. Code without any context or explanation isn't very helpful to most people IMHO, unless they are fans of cargo-cult copy-and-paste techniques for solving their problems

Comment: @ADyson I understand your point but feel like there's a reasonable amount of explanation and links to documentation. Not sure how much spoon-feeding is necessary.

Comment: Well you've edited it since my original comment, and it's an improvement